# Php code not giving response

Tags: php, mysql, json

The following code does show anything in the browser . All the database name and table name are correct . While adding a line echo json_encode($temp) in the while loop displays result as objects.

```
 <?php 
     define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
     define('DB_USER', 'root');
     define('DB_PASS', '');
     define('DB_NAME', 'sample_userdata');

     $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       die();
     }

     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT questions FROM sample_questions;");

     $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->bind_result($post);

     $userdata = array(); 

     while($stmt->fetch()){
       $temp = array();
       $temp['questions'] =$post;


       array_push($userdata,$temp);
     }

     echo json_encode($userdata);
     ?>
```

Comment: The `[sql-server]` tag refers to Microsoft SQL Server, not SQL servers in general.

Comment: If you get no output you probably have errors, so check your error log. If you don't know where that is now's the time to find out.

Comment: Check your error log and add this code in the top of the errors is not show up ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: the local host webpage is blank

Comment: Check the server error logs to see if there's anything there, and also check the Network tab of your Developer console to see if it's giving a 500 error or a 200 error (won't tell you what's wrong, but that will confirm if the page is broken)

Comment: Incredible hat it does not work , so there is a table containing column "questions" with 6 rows, I want to display the rows as array , but the above code does not return any json array , when I put 'echo json_encode($temp)' in the while loop it displays 6 rows as objects , not in array

Comment: What you have described ... Having `echo json_encode($userdata);` after the while loop would be outputting all those objects as one json array. Since you claim it is not, then your code as presented here is not the code you are using.

Comment: I am also surprised , a similar file with with exact same code but different table outputs the json array

Comment: I got it , when I put 'echo json_last_error_msg();' it tells 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

Comment: Why are you using `$temp['questions'] = $post;  array_push(userdata, $temp);` when you can get rid of the $temp array altogether with `$userdata[] = array('questions' => $post);`?  Won't solve the problem, but reduces the number of stray and random variables being re-initialized in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you use json_decode() function it creates object for array with keys

```
$x['test1'] = 1;
$x['test2'] = 2;
echo json_encode($x);
// Result: {"test1":1,"test2":2}
```

You can remove keys using array_values()

```
$x['test1'] = 1;
$x['test2'] = 2;
echo json_encode(array_values($x));
// Result: [1,2]
```